# Import data from XLS file to SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

Here's our situation:

We have:

- SI = 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
- DB = SQL Server 2008 R2

NO Microsoft Office package are installed on this server (we can't open .xls, .ppt, .doc etc)

We tried to import an Excel 97-2003 file using the wizard and everything worked!

The problem is: we need to execute a query with some control in it that imports data from the Excel file into our database.

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\file.xls', 'SELECT * FROM [Clienti$]')
```

but we get the following error:

> Msg 7308, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

We already configured some options following this [guide](https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/321686/how-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server)

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Why don't you use SSIS instead? That's the easiest way to load *and* transform data. That's what the wizard uses. You can even *save* the package generated by the wizard and edit it. This will give you far more control that running a query against a single file. Eg you could use a File iterator container to load all `.xls` file in a specific folder, then move them to an archive folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly according to [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5b29496-d6a1-4ecf-b1a4-5550d80b84b6/microsoftjetoledb40-32bit-and-64bit?forum=adodotnetdataproviders&forum=adodotnetdataproviders):

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not supported for 64-bit OS.

Additionally [this link](https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm) may be helpful to work through.

Try change 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' to 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'?

Comment: It *is* supported on x64 operating systems, as long as you install the *correct* driver.

Comment: Besides, the error has nothing to do with bitness at all. The driver *was* loaded, otherwise the error would be different